# Running a service will not bind to ports # 443 and # 80 despite application of sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/binary

Tags: networking, server, bind, setcap

The service starts and attemps to listen to port # 443, I get errno=99 which is EADDRNOTAVAIL and std::strerror(errno) reports "Cannot assign requested address".

If I run sudo getcap /path/to/binary I get this:
/usr/local/binary_file = cap_net_bind_service+ep

This seems to mean that it has the capability, yet I can not bind to the port, anyone can help me with this issue?

Comment: can we assume you verified that there's not another process already bound to the port(s) in question? if so, how?

Comment: @steeldriver I used $sudo netstat -plan --protocol=inet and got port # 22 and # 54 in LISTEN state, nothing about port # 443 or #80

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I specified the wrong ipaddress in my bind, that came from an environment variable passed at compilation time. Setcap works great.